# simple encrypting / decrypting in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged, cryptostream

I'm trying to figure out how to encrypt / decrypt a string in VB.Net.

I followed the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922536/rijndael-managed-plaintext-length-detction) and wrote the following code (below).  There's a text box, an "encrypt" button, and a "decrypt" button.  The idea is to type something into the text box ("like 'hello world'"), click "encrypt", and see the encrypted version appear in the text box.  Clicking "decrypt" should then take you back to the original string.

But when I try to encrypt I get an error when I try to "FlushFinalBlock".  The error is: "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid".

The "decrypt" part is a total shot in the dark, as the example quoted above only deals with encryption, not decryption.  I'm sure it's wrong, but since I can't get "encrypt" to work I haven't tested it yet.

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Form1

  Private cryptObj As RijndaelManaged
  Private KEY_128 As Byte() = {42, 1, 52, 67, 231, 13, 94, 101, 123, 6, 0, 12, 32, 91, 4, 111, 31, 70, 21, 141, 123, 142, 234, 82, 95, 129, 187, 162, 12, 55, 98, 23}
  Private IV_128 As Byte() = {234, 12, 52, 44, 214, 222, 200, 109, 2, 98, 45, 76, 88, 53, 23, 78}
  Private enc As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()

  Private Sub btnEncrypt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEncrypt.Click
    Dim sPlainText As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText) Then
      Dim bPlainText As Byte() = Me.enc.GetBytes(Me.TextBox1.Text)
      Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
      Dim cs As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(ms, cryptObj.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
      cs.Write(bPlainText, 0, sPlainText.Length)
      cs.FlushFinalBlock()
      Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.enc.GetString(ms.ToArray())
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnDecrypt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDecrypt.Click
    Dim sCipherText = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    Dim cs As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(ms, cryptObj.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    cs.Read(Me.enc.GetBytes(sCipherText), 0, sCipherText.Length)
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.enc.GetString(ms.ToArray())
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Me.cryptObj = New RijndaelManaged()
    Me.cryptObj.BlockSize = 128
    Me.cryptObj.KeySize = 128
    Me.cryptObj.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    Me.cryptObj.Padding = PaddingMode.None
    Me.cryptObj.Key = KEY_128
    Me.cryptObj.IV = IV_128
  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ultimately I found the answer here:

http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx

His example seems a little over-complicated. I'm sure it represents a more general and flexible case, but I was able to do away with the "saltPhrase", the "initVector", and the use of "PasswordDeriveBytes", which apparently is deprecated anyway, but I also avoided its nastily named replacement: Rfc2898DeriveBytes.

The following lets you enter a string of any length, encrypt it, and re-decrypt it.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography

Public Class Form1

  Private enc As System.Text.UTF8Encoding
  Private encryptor As ICryptoTransform
  Private decryptor As ICryptoTransform

  Private Sub btnEncrypt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEncrypt.Click
    Dim sPlainText As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText) Then
      Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
      Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, Me.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
      cryptoStream.Write(Me.enc.GetBytes(sPlainText), 0, sPlainText.Length)
      cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
      Me.TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray())
      memoryStream.Close()
      cryptoStream.Close()
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub btnDecrypt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDecrypt.Click
    Dim cypherTextBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Me.TextBox1.Text)
    Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(cypherTextBytes)
    Dim cryptoStream As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(memoryStream, Me.decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read)
    Dim plainTextBytes(cypherTextBytes.Length) As Byte
    Dim decryptedByteCount As Integer = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length)
    memoryStream.Close()
    cryptoStream.Close()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.enc.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount)
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim KEY_128 As Byte() = {42, 1, 52, 67, 231, 13, 94, 101, 123, 6, 0, 12, 32, 91, 4, 111, 31, 70, 21, 141, 123, 142, 234, 82, 95, 129, 187, 162, 12, 55, 98, 23}
    Dim IV_128 As Byte() = {234, 12, 52, 44, 214, 222, 200, 109, 2, 98, 45, 76, 88, 53, 23, 78}
    Dim symmetricKey As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC

    Me.enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
    Me.encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(KEY_128, IV_128)
    Me.decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(KEY_128, IV_128)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example of an Encryption class based on my [NextLevelEncryption](https://nextlevelencryption.codeplex.com) library.

```
Public Class Encryption
''' <summary>
''' Encrypt text using AES Algorithm
''' </summary>
''' <param name="text">Text to encrypt</param>
''' <param name="password">Password with which to encrypt</param>
''' <returns>Returns encrypted text</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function Encrypt(text As String, password As String) As String
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
    Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim encrypted As String = ""
    Dim hash(31) As Byte
        Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password))
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
        AES.Key = hash
        AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateEncryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text)
        encrypted = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return encrypted
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Decrypt text using AES Algorithm
''' </summary>
''' <param name="text">Text to decrypt</param>
''' <param name="password">Password with which to decrypt</param>
''' <returns>Returns decrypted text</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function Decrypt(text As String, password As String) As String
    Dim AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
    Dim Hash_AES As New System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    Dim decrypted As String = ""
    Dim hash(31) As Byte
        Dim temp As Byte() = Hash_AES.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password))
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 0, 16)
        Array.Copy(temp, 0, hash, 15, 16)
        AES.Key = hash
        AES.Mode = Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        Dim DESDecrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = AES.CreateDecryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(text)
        decrypted = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DESDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
    Return decrypted
End Function
End Class
```

To use it all you have to do is call the function `Encrypt("Your text to encrypt here","Your password")` and `Decrypt(""Your text to encrypt here","Your password")`.

For more information head over to https://nextlevelencryption.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your encryption looks mostly correct, but I am not sure if the UTF8 encoding or other settings on the encryption object is throwing you off. Here is the heart of the encryption method that we use, tailored slightly to your code:

```
' Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
Dim aoBytes As Byte() = Nothing

' Declare the RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.
Using oEncryptor As New RijndaelManaged
    Try
        ' Initialize the encryptor with the specified key and initialization vector
        oEncryptor.Key = KEY_128
        oEncryptor.IV = IV_128

        ' Declare the streams used to encrypt to an in memory array of bytes.
        Using msEncrypt As New MemoryStream
            ' Create the streams used for encryption.
            Using csEncrypt As New CryptoStream(msEncrypt, oEncryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                Using swEncrypt As New StreamWriter(csEncrypt)
                    ' Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(Me.TextBox1.Text)
                End Using

                ' Retrieve the bytes
                aoBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray()
            End Using

        End Using
    Finally
        ' Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
        If oEncryptor IsNot Nothing Then
            oEncryptor.Clear()
        End If
    End Try
End Using

If aoBytes IsNot Nothing Then
    Me.TextBox1.Text = System.Convert.ToBase64String(aoBytes)
Else
    Me.TextBox1.Text = String.Empty
End If
```

And the decryption is:

```
Dim sDecryptedValue As String = ""

' Declare the RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.
Using oDecryptor As New RijndaelManaged
    Try
        ' Initialize the encryptor with the specified key and a default initialization vector
        oDecryptor.Key = KEY_128
        oDecryptor.IV = IV_128

        Using msDecrypt As New MemoryStream(System.Convert.FromBase64String(Me.TextBox1.Text))
            ' Create the streams used for encryption.
            Using csDecrypt As New CryptoStream(msDecrypt, oDecryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
                Using srDecrypt As New StreamReader(csDecrypt)
                    ' Write all data to the stream.
                    sDecryptedValue = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Finally
        ' Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
        If oDecryptor IsNot Nothing Then
            oDecryptor.Clear()
        End If
    End Try
End Using

Me.TextBox1.Text = sDecryptedValue
```

One minor difference is that we accept a string key and intializaton vector from the caller and clean them up as follows.

InitializationVector cleanup:

```
If sInitializationVector.Length > 16 Then
    ' Trim the IV if it is too long
    sInitializationVector = sInitializationVector.Substring(0, 16)
ElseIf sInitializationVector.Length < 16 Then
    ' Pad the IV if it is too short
    sInitializationVector = sInitializationVector.PadRight(16)
End If

oDecryptor.IV = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(sInitializationVector)
```

Encryption key cleanup:

```
oDecryptor.Key = GetLegalEncryptionKey(sKey, oDecryptor)

Public Function GetLegalEncryptionKey(ByVal sKey As String, ByVal oEncryptor As RijndaelManaged) As Byte()

Dim sTemp As String

If oEncryptor.LegalKeySizes.Length > 0 Then
    Dim wSize As Integer
    ' key sizes are in bits

    With oEncryptor.LegalKeySizes(0)
        wSize = .MinSize
        Do While sKey.Length * 8 > wSize AndAlso .SkipSize > 0 AndAlso wSize < .MaxSize
            wSize += oEncryptor.LegalKeySizes(0).SkipSize
        Loop
    End With
    Dim wTotalChars As Integer

    wTotalChars = CInt(wSize / 8)
    If sKey.Length > wTotalChars Then
        sTemp = sKey.Substring(0, wTotalChars)
    Else
        sTemp = sKey.PadRight(wTotalChars, " "c)
    End If
Else
    sTemp = sKey
End If

' convert the secret key to byte array
Return System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(sTemp)
```

End Function

Comment: I tried doing the encrypt using something like what you have above. Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(cs); sw.Write(Me.TextBox1.Text); Dim aoBytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray(); Me.TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(aoBytes) But the result was that it blanked the text field. "aoBytes" comes out with a length of 0. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but part of the problem is with all these streams and writers flying around I'm pretty much just shooting in the dark without much knowledge of what these things are actually doing.

Comment: The problem could be with your key and initialization vector. Try changing them to strings and using the optional code I provided to see if that works. If needed, I can revise the answer to show exactly where they fit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I spotted is on this line in your encryption code:

> Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.enc.GetString(ms.ToArray())

The problem is this assumes your byte array is *already* a UTF-8 string, just carved up as a byte array, when in fact it should be random bytes and likely includes unprintable characters. It's not valid utf-8 data.

What you want to do instead is base-64 encode that byte array using the [Convert.ToBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx) function. Then, your decryption needs to correctly convert that base 64 string back to a byte array, using the [Convert.FromBase64String()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) method.

Comment: This may well be a problem, but I don't think it addresses the problem in the question.  For now I'm just trying to encode text typed into the TextBox from the keyboard, which will be a valid UTF-8 string.  Error of "Length of the data to encrypt is invalid" still occurs at "cs.FlushFinalBlock"